# Autosys box job not finishing

Tags: autosys

I am new to Autosys and facing difficulty setting up some jobs. I have a box job containg a few command jobs. One of those command jobs may or may not run. The problem is when this job doesn't run(it remains in activated state), it keeps the box running. I have to terminate this job or the box every time such situation arises.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how your jobs are supposed to work, so posting JIL or a more detailed description would help, but:

- You can add a "box_success" JIL attribute on your box job to define conditions that will cause the box to complete even without all the jobs running or completing.
- You could consider moving the optional job outside of the box so that this issue goes away. But consider that the box could then complete while the optional job is running so make sure that you don't then have jobs running out of sequence or overlapping when they shouldn't.